# How can I make Firefox download different file types to different locations?

Tags: firefox, download

98% of what I download is music, so I set the download location to my music folder. However, the other 2% has no place there, so every time I download `.doc` files or PDF files I have to remove them. Is there a way to make Firefox change the download folder based on file extension? I'll settle for all non-MP3 files getting saved to the desktop.

I know I can right click, choose `Save Link As` and pick the download location myself, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 8):

[Automatic Save Folder](http://asf.mangaheart.org/)

Comment: +1 I can't see any solution easier than this....

Comment: +1 for this. You can also filter by domain etc. Very handy add-on.

Comment: Interesting, can it be used together with FlashGot addon or it works only with the builtin downloader?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/

Comment: Didn't on firefox 34.0.2 Windows 7

Comment: Not working anymore with Firefox Quantum

Answer (score 2):

Again, this is non a Firefox solution, but if you really want to automate where various file types should go from your download folder try Belevedere (see here:http://lifehacker.com/341950/ ). You can set up rules to automatically send different file tyoes to different folders and tell it how often you want it to "look" - I find it great.

Just a little tip - this had me foxed for a while - once you've installed it and you click on the Desktop Icon it doesn't "open up" -you have to look for its icon in the task bar. You can also tell it to start every time Windows start.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can always use DownThemAll then use the dTaOneClick function from the download dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up not finding a Firefox-based solution you could just make a simple batch script that runs when Windows boots; this would move files from the central download directory to other places based on their extension. It's not instant, but it gets the job done and keeps things organized.

I suppose if you want things organized instantly, you could just run the script periodically on your own or run it periodically using Windows' Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate Folder Watcher program such as [this](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/2010/07/watch-4-folder-22.html) (an example not a recommendation) to shift the files as they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar but much more varied use case , so I had to find a solution to navigating around lots of different folder structures.

I wound up finding the program [Direct Folders](http://codesector.com/directfolders).  This lets me set up links to certain directories and I can middle click and select them instantly when I save a file, rather than navigate a complex folder structure.  Also, when Firefox randomly decides to go to a different folder, you can get a wrangle on it.

This might be overkill for your particular use case, but my use case is similar.  If the other solutions don't work for you, this one will.

I'm not affiliated with Code Sector, but I do like several of their softwares.