# Is there a way to set download directory for files in Firefox by file type?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make firefox download different file-types to different locations?](https://superuser.com/questions/197550/how-can-i-make-firefox-download-different-file-types-to-different-locations)

Is there any way to set the directory where a file will be downloaded by default by file type or at least extension?

For example I'd like to have a video directory which would be download directory for video files by default and have an audio directory which would be download directory for audio files by default at the same time.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Thanks a lot! Automatic Save Folder looks just like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla haven't included a Download Manager that technical into their browser, it's just a basic simple downloader.

Look at a download manager like Internet Download Accelerator or Free Download Manager in order to download through file type.

Use the [Flashgot addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) for Firefox to connect the download manager to the browser.