# How to save files to different folders based on extension?

Tags: firefox, file-types

I'm using Firefox 4. Whenever I'm prompted to save a file then the folder is where I saved something the previous time.

How could I achieve that when I'm downloading for example an .exe file then FF "knows" that I want to save it every time to Folder1. But all .zip files would go into Folder2 etc.

FF add-ons are acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make firefox download different file-types to different locations?](http://superuser.com/questions/197550/how-can-i-make-firefox-download-different-file-types-to-different-locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This add-on works great for me : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/
you can filter by extension or domain name.

Comment: Thanks, this seems perfect. Just FYI - your link opens the French version of the add-ons site. The English page is at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/

Comment: This extension is no longer compatible with recent versions of Firefox.